# Paragraph Generator using BERT or GPT

Tags: nlp, bert, gpt

I am trying to generate similar sentences, called paragraph generation. For example, what is the name of the eldest brother of ram? - For these paragraphs can be - who is the oldest brother of ram? , Who is the oldest blood brother of ram? , I want to know the eldest sibling of ram.  etc etc

BERT and OpenAI GPT are one of the most powerful NLP systems, as per my knowledge, at least for now. However, I heard that BERT is based on MLM so it cant be used for sentence generation, but can be used for word prediction.

Can OpenAI GPT be used for this purpose? If so, please give some pointer.
If any other name is in mind which is the State of Art please suggest.